# How to make builder pattern thread safe in the multithreading environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, builder

I am working on a project in which I need to have synchronous and asynchronous method of my java client. Some customer will call synchronous and some customer will call asynchronous method of my java client depending on there requirement.

Below is my java client which has `synchronous` and `asynchronous` methods -

```
public class TestingClient implements IClient {

    private ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    // for synchronous
    @Override
    public String executeSync(ClientKey keys) {

        String response = null;
        try {

            Future<String> handle = executeAsync(keys);
            response = handle.get(keys.getTimeout(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        return response;
    }

    // for asynchronous
    @Override
    public Future<String> executeAsync(ClientKey keys) {

        Future<String> future = null;

        try {
            ClientTask ClientTask = new ClientTask(keys, restTemplate);
            future = service.submit(ClientTask);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }

        return future;
    }
}
```

And now below is my `ClientTask` class  which implements Callable interface and I am passing around the dependency using DI pattern in the `ClientTask class`. In the call method, I am just making a URL basis on `machineIPAddress` and using the `ClientKeys` which is passed to `ClientTask` class and then hit the server using `RestTemplate` and get the response back -

```
class ClientTask implements Callable<String> {

    private ClientKey cKeys;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public ClientTask(ClientKey cKeys, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
        this.cKeys = cKeys;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {

        // .. some code here
        String url = generateURL("machineIPAddress");           
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

        return response;
    }

    // is this method thread safe and the way I am using `cKeys` variable here is also thread safe?
    private String generateURL(final String hostIPAdress) throws Exception {
        StringBuffer url = new StringBuffer();
        url.append("http://" + hostIPAdress + ":8087/user?user_id=" + cKeys.getUserId() + "&client_id="
            + cKeys.getClientId());

        final Map<String, String> paramMap = cKeys.getParameterMap();
        Set<Entry<String, String>> params = paramMap.entrySet();
        for (Entry<String, String> e : params) {
            url.append("&" + e.getKey());
            url.append("=" + e.getValue());
        }

        return url.toString();
    }
}
```

And below is my `ClientKey` class using Builder patter which customer will use to make the input parameters to pass to the `TestingClient` -

```
public final class ClientKey {

    private final long userId;
    private final int clientId;
    private final long timeout;
    private final boolean testFlag;
    private final Map<String, String> parameterMap;

    private ClientKey(Builder builder) {
    this.userId = builder.userId;
    this.clientId = builder.clientId;
    this.remoteFlag = builder.remoteFlag;
    this.testFlag = builder.testFlag;
    this.parameterMap = builder.parameterMap;
    this.timeout = builder.timeout;
    }

    public static class Builder {
    protected final long userId;
    protected final int clientId;
    protected long timeout = 200L;
    protected boolean remoteFlag = false;
    protected boolean testFlag = true;
    protected Map<String, String> parameterMap;

    public Builder(long userId, int clientId) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public Builder parameterMap(Map<String, String> parameterMap) {
        this.parameterMap = parameterMap;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder remoteFlag(boolean remoteFlag) {
        this.remoteFlag = remoteFlag;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder testFlag(boolean testFlag) {
        this.testFlag = testFlag;
        return this;
    }

    public Builder addTimeout(long timeout) {
        this.timeout = timeout;
        return this;
    }

    public ClientKey build() {
        return new ClientKey(this);
    }
    }

    public long getUserId() {
    return userId;
    }

    public int getClientId() {
    return clientId;
    }

    public long getTimeout() {
    return timeout;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getParameterMap() {
    return parameterMap;

    public boolean istestFlag() {
    return testFlag;
    }
}
```

Is my above code thread safe as I am using `ClientKey` variables in `ClientTask` class in multithreaded environment so not sure what will happen if another thread tries to make `ClientKey` variable while making a call to `TestingClient` synchronous method -

Because customer will be making a call to us with the use of below code and they can call us from there Multithreaded application as well -

```
IClient testClient = ClientFactory.getInstance();

Map<String, String> testMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
testMap.put("hello", "world");

ClientKey keys = new ClientKey.Builder(12345L, 200).addTimeout(2000L).parameterMap(testMap).build();

String response = testClient.executeSync(keys);
```

So just trying to understand whether my above code will be thread safe or not as they can pass multiple values to my `TestingClient` class from multiple threads. I am having a feeling that my `ClientKey` class is not thread safe because of `parameterMap` but not sure.

**And also do I need `StringBuffer` here or `StringBuilder` will be fine as StringBuilder is faster than StringBuffer because it's not synchronized.**

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: If you want to be sure that the parameterMap cannot be modified after being assigned to ClientKey, you need to do something like: `this.parameterMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<String, String>(builder.parameterMap))` but if multiple threads were accessing an unsynchronized LinkedHashMap currently, you already had a problem in your code outside ClientKey.

Comment: Thanks Erwin for the suggestion.. Customer can pass different values from different thread to `TestingClient` class which means they need to use `ClientKey` class to make the input parameters always as userId will keep on changing for each call they are passing and same with ParameterMap as well.. And `LinkedHashMap` code was an example how customer will call us from there application. They can have ConcurrentHashMap at that place as it there code how they are making a call to us..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `ClientKey keys` is given, so I assume is always different.

I don't see any synchronization issues with your code, I'll explain:

```
ClientTask ClientTask = new ClientTask(keys, restTemplate);
future = service.submit(ClientTask);
```

- Creating a `ClientTask` object from inside the method, which is not shared among threads.
- Using `service.submit`, whih returns a Future object
- The `ClientTask` object read the keys only inside the method `generateURL`, but, as I said before, the `ClientKeys` object is given as a parameter, so you are good as long as this object is not being shared.

In summary, the thread-safeness of your code depends on `ExecutorService` and `Future` being thread safe.

Update: Clarification for `as long as this object is not being shared`

```
ClientKeys keys;
add keys to @keys
.. code
executeAsync(.., keys)
... code
add keys to @keys
add keys to @keys
executeAsync(.., keys)
executeAsync(.., keys)
add keys to @keys
... code
add keys to @keys
executeAsync(.., keys)
```

This is (more and less) what I meant is sharing. `keys` is being used in several threads due to the calls to executeAsync(). In this case, some threads are reading `keys`, and others are `writing` data to it, causing whats is ussualy called a [race condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510/what-is-a-race-condition).

Update 2: The `StringBuffer` object is local to (aka is in the scope of) `generateURL`, there's no need to synchronize it.

Comment: Thanks ichramm for the suggestion. I always gets confused when people say `as long as this object is not being shared.` What does this mean actually? As Clientkey keys will be different for each call..

Comment: So in my scenario do you see this is going to happen?

Comment: Based on what you wrote about your customers, and the last code chunk, no, I don't think it will happen.

Comment: I see. And also do I need StringBuffer here or StringBuilder will be fine in my `generateURL` method as StringBuilder is faster than StringBuffer because it's not synchronized.

Comment: The `StringBuffer` object is local to *(aka is in the scope of)* `generateURL`, there's no need to synchronize it.

Comment: @SSH Note that you should accept this answer (click the green checkmark) if it solved your problem